# how to show a diameter function exist by using compactness and closeness

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $A,B \in \Bbb C$. and say

$$d(A,B)=\inf{|a-b|:a \in A,b\in B }$$  is distance between $A$ and $B$. if $B=\{b\}$ is with one component then let's show $d(A,\{b\})=d(A,b)$.

a) if $A\in\Bbb C$ is closed and $b\in\Bbb C$ is any complex number then show that there is an $a\in A$
such as $$d(A,b)=|a-b|$$
b) if $A\in\Bbb C$ is closed and $B\in \Bbb C$ is compact then show that there are such $a\in A$ and $b\in B $ such as 
$$d(A,B)=|a-b|$$
How can I do this? I know from H.Borel theorem $A\in \Bbb C$ is closed and bounded iff A is compact. So will we use its boundedness?

Comment: The same proof you will ues for b) use it for a) too,because {$b$} is compact.

Comment: If $A$ was compact would (a) be straightforward?  Then show that if a point in $A$ is 'far enough' away, then it is not a candidate for nearest point. Use this to reduce the general case to the case where $A$ is compact. The same trick can be used for (b).

Comment: @copper.hat sorry I dont understand. so if A isnt compact we can reduce A to a set $K\in A$ which is bounded. and K will be a compact set and then we can get a=inf(K)?

Comment: @Dimitris could you please be more specific?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(a) Let $a' \in A$, and let $r = |a'-b|+1$. Then $d(A, \{b\}) = d(A \cap \bar{B}(b,r), \{ b \})$.

To see this, we note that $d(A, \{b\}) \le d(A \cap \bar{B}(b,r), \{ b \})$ just by set inclusion. Now suppose $a_n \in A$ is such that $|a_n-b| \to d(A, \{b\})$. 
Since $d(A, \{b\}) < r$, we must have some $N$ such that $|a_n-b|< r$ for all $n \ge N$, and so $a_n \in \bar{B}(b,r)$. Hence $d(A \cap \bar{B}(b,r), \{ b \}) \le |a_n-b|$, and we have that $d(A, \{b\}) = d(A \cap \bar{B}(b,r), \{ b \})$.

Since $A \cap \bar{B}(b,r)$ is compact and $a \mapsto |a-b|$ is continuous, we see that the minimum is achieved some some $\hat{a} \in A \cap \bar{B}(b,r) \subset A$. That is, $d(A, \{b\}) = |\hat{a}-b|$.

(b) You can repeat the above trick (appropriately adjusted), or try the following:

Let $\phi(b) = d(A, \{b\})$. Note that $d(A,B) = \inf_{b\in B} d(A, \{b\}) = \inf_{b \in B} \phi(b)$.

Now choose $b,b'$ and note that $|b'-a| \le |b-a|+ |b'-b|$. Taking the $\inf$ on the left first, we get
$\inf_{a'\in A} |b'-a'| \le |b-a|+|b'-b|$. Now take the $\inf$ on the right to  get $\inf_{a'\in A} |b'-a'| \le \inf_{a\in A}|b-a|+|b'-b|$, which gives $\phi(b') \le \phi(b) + |b'-b|$. Repeating with $b,b'$ swapped and combining gives $|\phi(b)-\phi(b')| \le |b-b'|$. Hence $\phi$ is continuous (in fact, Lipschitz continuous with rank one).

It follows that $\phi$ attains a minimum at some $\hat{b} \in B$, and so 
$d(A,B) =  \min_{b\in B} d(A, \{b\}) = d(A, \{\hat{b}\})$. Part (a) shows that there exists some $\hat{a}$ such that $d(A, \{\hat{b}\}) = |\hat{a}-\hat{b}|$, and so we have $d(A,B) = |\hat{a}-\hat{b}|$ for some $\hat{a} \in A, \hat{b} \in B$.